# AttributeError: module 'pygame.event' has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python from "Code this game", hit into an error in my first attempt:

AttributeError: module 'pygame.event' has no attribute 'type'

Source code as follows:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
pygame.init()
WINDOW_WIDTH = 900
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
WINDOW_RES = (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
GAME_WINDOW = display.set_mode(WINDOW_RES)
display.set_caption('Attack of the Vampire Pizzas!')
game_running = True
while game_running:
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            game_running = False

    display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Thank you!!
DK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit "`event.type`" to "`events.type`"

```
if events.type == QUIT:
```